# I miss Management Tools features when installing in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I downloaded SQL Server 2016 and try to install but when selected feature I don't know why but I cant find Management Tools in Features I searched a lot but I cant find any solution.

[image: Screenshot]

I know after "Documentation Components" should be Management Tools but it doesn't?

I uninstalled SQL Server 2014 before installing this.

Comment: You mean SSMS? You can download it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: yeah,but always there was in features and just selected to install,could you tell me why there isn't in features ??

Comment: It's not there because now you can install it separately without needing to download the huge package -- and Microsoft can also release it with a faster cycle

Answer (score 1):

It was decoupled from SQL Server setup to allow for different servicing model and different update frequency. It can be now downloaded and installed independently of SQL Server.

Comment: Really really stupid move by Microsoft. Just forces users to to take another step when installing SQL Server. It takes a real genius to mess up something that just works by not installing all the tools at once. Here is a very successful, profitable product and someone has decided to complicate things.

Comment: There is some merit to it. This way they can have much more frequent updates, which is important because Azure database doesn't follow the same release cycle as the on-premise SQL Server, and they want you to have a version of SSMS you can use to manage possible new features in Azure before they are pushed to on-premise, rather than have you wait for whenever vNext is released. And they will (are?) pushing it with Windows update.